# Ruby on Rails to Visual studio

Tags: ruby

I have a software written in Ruby on Rails. Is it possible to migrate/convert the data/codes into Visual basic or C#?

Comment: I believe, only by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Why convert? [Iron Ruby is your friend](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby/running-rails-2-3-x-on-ironruby/).

Comment: It's not in the .net framework and (correct me if I'm wrong) is not supported in sharepoint. What about ironruby?